# Can't use data fetched from graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-js

```
const Products = async()=> {
    try {
      const result= await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listProducts));
      const products = result.data.listProducts.items;
      console.log(products);
      let y = []
      if (products){
       for (let x in products){
       y.push(x.name);
       }
      }
      console.log(y);
  
     } catch (err) { 
      console.log('error fetching products');
      }
      } ;
```

I am able to view the result but why does it show an array full of undefined items.
o/p for y :

> [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]

Comment: What kind of data is inside products? can you attach a `console.log(products)`.

Comment: basically its an array : Array(15)
0: {id: '2', name: 'Baseball', description: 'PRODUCT''}
1: {id: '13', name: 'Hat', description: 'PRODUCT'}
2: {id: '8', name: 'Cardio', description: 'Activity''}
3: {id: '9', name: 'Weight Training ', description: 'Activity''}... and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bad idea to use `for...in` for looping, you can map the values instead of using a `for...in` or just use regular loop.

```js
if (products){
    products.map((x) => y.push(x.name));
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much man..  it worked !!! could you please tell me what went wrong while using a for-loop ?

Comment: you can use regular for loop and it should be fine, but u used `for...in` which is not recommended for looping through arrays or array-like objects in your case, you can find why this is the case in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-for-array-iteration-a-bad-idea). Throw me an upvote, if you find it useful. :)

Comment: i really want to for sure..  this is my first question on stackoverflow .. theres's something called 15 reputation before i can make any upvotes .. thanks again for your help !!!